# How do I sort something alphabetically (but the capital letters not as a group before the lowercase) in SilverStripe 3.1?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1 I can get a sorted list of `Children` by doing the following:

```
$this->Children()->sort('Title', 'ASC');
```

But when I do this the capital letters (as a group) come before the lowercase (as a group); thus "D" comes before "a":

> Aadb
>   Bdbdd
>   Cdbd
>   Dbddb
>   aeb

But I want a sort order like this:

> Aadb
>   aeb
>   Bdbdd
>   Cdbd
>   Dbddb

How can I do this in SilverStripe?

**EDIT**

I found a similar [question](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/42649) where Willr says:

> Strange! I would have thought it would be case insensitive. You could simply export the array list as an array ($list->map()) then write your own sort logic.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried the following but it does not return any results:

```
function SortedChildren(){
    $sortChildren = $this->Children()->map();
    natcasesort($sortChildren);
    return $sortChildren;
}
```

Comment: Maybe... $this->Children()->sort('LOWER(Title)', 'ASC')

Comment: No, unfortunately it do not work like this..

Comment: Which database are you using? Is this PostgreSQL?

Comment: What about a ":nocase" modifier? See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/

Comment: how can I use ":nocase" with "->sort()"?

Comment: to be honest - don't know :) since I only used it with filters and probable it just works with those - just a shot in the dark :(

Comment: `$this->Children()->sort('LOWER(Title)');` works for me. I am using a MySQL database. When you try this do you get an error? Or does it simply not sort it correctly?

Comment: Hi, no there is no error but `$this->Children()->sort('LOWER(Title)');` just don't sort it correctly. It looks like it sort it by the date the pages where created.

Comment: Lower is the way to go. "SELECT title FROM children ORDER BY LOWER(title )“

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I figured out how to write and use my own sort logic:

```
function SortChildren() {

     $_list = $this->Children()->map("URLSegment", "Title");
     natcasesort($_list);

     $sortedChildren = new ArrayList();
     foreach($_list as $key => $value ){
         $fields = new ArrayData(array('ChildURL' => $key, 'Title' => $value));
         $sortedChildren->push($fields);
     }  
     return $sortedChildren;

}
```

And then use in template:

```
<% loop SortChildren %>
      <div class="child"><a href="$ChildURL">$Title</a></div>
<% end_loop %>
```